# c# insert data in FileMaker table using ODBC sql

Tags: c#, odbc, filemaker

I have created an application which will insert the values in filemaker database.

I have create the connection using ODBC and it works fine and insert also works fine.

After insert the record the lookup field value is not updated automatically.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            OdbcConnection conn = null;
            OdbcCommand cmd = null;
            OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            string temp = "";

            try
            {
                //DRIVER=FileMaker ODBC;
                conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=SecureDSN;UID=***;PWD=***");
                conn.Open();

                Console.WriteLine(conn.State);

                if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

                    Console.WriteLine("Input value text");

                    string code = Console.ReadLine();

                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(Field1) VALUES ('test')";
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    cmd.Dispose();


                    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        int fCount = dt.Rows.Count;
                        Console.WriteLine(fCount);

                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("gBarcode=" + Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["gBarCode"]));
                            Console.WriteLine("Boolean=" + Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Boolean"]));
                            Console.WriteLine("cBoolean=" + Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["cBoolean"]));
                        }
                    }

                    da.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                }



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

This works fine but I am unable to get the values which is lookup value in MyTable.

When I enter the value in filemaker form the value of Boolean field is updated. Why its not calculated from SQL query. Please let me know the solution of this.

Comment: Don't use lookups, use auto-enter.

Comment: please let me know the code snippet how to use auto-enter. highly appreciated for your help

Comment: There is a field named Boolean which is a lookup field. When I enter the values from FileMaker layout the Value is Showing after insert. But I insert the value from C# ODBC query the lookup value is not updated. How to get the value of Lookup field after insert.

Comment: Change the field definition in FileMaker. Go to File/Manage/Databases, open your table and select your field. Uncheck "Looked-up value" and select "Calculated value", specify the field you want to copy over in calculation dialogue. The field has to be from related table.

Comment: I have changed the datatype to calculated and change specify another field which is calculated. It doesn't work. it works only with auto update.

Comment: Also unable to get value of Calculation data type fields. I created the new field to copy the value. It update the same but in my select statement it will shows blank. in my sql select statement the field shows blank.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM MyTable" shows only Text fields value not Calculation fields.

Comment: Are you sure they are from the same table? Select should display calculation fields just fine. Try to add a calc field and set the result of the calculation to 1.

Comment: suppose there a calculated field named "cUser" which auto fill after insert. I just created another field with Text datatype and calculated to cUser named "cCopyUser" and try. It won't work. Unable to get the value.

Comment: Could you provide me screen shot or example

Comment: I tried to get value of calculated field but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It works if the calculation field doesn't have any relational values in it, but when we have relational values then it return empty.